# jQuery is to be used with Web Forms or HTML Forms?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am studying asp.net and jQuery, and I found that there several approaches for creating forms in html.

Being a windows developer, I find that the most common methods are the following:

1. HTML Forms
2. ASP.NET WebForms
3. ASP.NET MVC
4. jQuery
5. AJAX

Now, I would like to understand a little bit more about the differences. I see that Html Forms is the most basic, which can be integrated by jQUERY, but also ASP.NET Webforms can be integrated by jQUERY.

a) Can I consider AJAX useless for a simple webform (post-get of json) if I use jQuery?

b) Can I consider MVC too much for a simple webform?

c) Which one would you choose, and why?

Thanks for your help, I have read so many websites that I'm super confused!

edit--

More details: I have a backend that provides jsons through REST calls, and I need to make some pages (frontend) that show the result of those calls (example: choose a date in the calendar, tell me if an appointment is available). The server logic is already there, I am trying to approach the best way for keeping it sharp, cool and clean (and good looking if possible!)

Answer (score 1):

> As for WebFroms:
>
> *ASP.NET Web Forms lets you build dynamic websites using a familiar drag-and-drop, event-driven model. A design surface and hundreds of
>   controls and components let you rapidly build sophisticated, powerful
>   UI-driven sites with data access.*

http://www.asp.net/web-forms

> As for MVC (Microsoft):
>
> ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic
>   websites that enables a clean separation of concerns and that gives
>   you full control over markup for enjoyable, agile development. ASP.NET
>   MVC includes many features that enable fast, TDD-friendly development
>   for creating sophisticated applications that use the latest web
>   standards.

http://www.asp.net/mvc

As for your questions:

a) Your question is little vague, I presume that you by AJAX mean [AJAX Control toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) by Microsoft? That is bunch of controls that enables you asynchronous retrieving data from server (in the background), without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page. And jQuery is JavaScript library, that has many more functions. It's not just for ajax-ing your data. You can use jQuery along your AJAX Controls.

b) Yes. `MVC` is basically a patterns-based way to create your web application**(Model-View-Controller)** but I think that you refer to Microsoft MVC. This is taken from [Microsoft MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview) site:

> Deciding When to Create an MVC Application
>
> You must consider carefully whether to implement a Web application by
>   using either the ASP.NET MVC framework or the ASP.NET Web Forms model.
>   The MVC framework does not replace the Web Forms model; you can use
>   either framework for Web applications. (If you have existing Web
>   Forms-based applications, these continue to work exactly as they
>   always have.)
>
> Before you decide to use the MVC framework or the Web Forms model for
>   a specific Web site, weigh the advantages of each approach.
>
> Advantages of an MVC-Based Web Application
>
> The ASP.NET MVC framework offers the following advantages:
>
> It makes it easier to manage complexity by dividing an application
>   into the model, the view, and the controller. It does not use view
>   state or server-based forms. This makes the MVC framework ideal for
>   developers who want full control over the behavior of an application.
>   It uses a Front Controller pattern that processes Web application
>   requests through a single controller. This enables you to design an
>   application that supports a rich routing infrastructure. For more
>   information, see Front Controller on the MSDN Web site. It provides
>   better support for test-driven development (TDD). It works well for
>   Web applications that are supported by large teams of developers and
>   Web designers who need a high degree of control over the application
>   behavior.
>
> Advantages of a Web Forms-Based Web Application
>
> The Web Forms-based framework offers the following advantages:
>
> It supports an event model that preserves state over HTTP, which
>   benefits line-of-business Web application development. The Web
>   Forms-based application provides dozens of events that are supported
>   in hundreds of server controls. It uses a Page Controller pattern that
>   adds functionality to individual pages. For more information, see Page
>   Controller on the MSDN Web site. It uses view state or server-based
>   forms, which can make managing state information easier. It works well
>   for small teams of Web developers and designers who want to take
>   advantage of the large number of components available for rapid
>   application development. In general, it is less complex for
>   application development, because the components (the Page class,
>   controls, and so on) are tightly integrated and usually require less
>   code than the MVC model.

You have good discussion about web-forms here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031/why-does-the-asp-net-web-forms-model-suck

**EDIT***

---

*The MVC programming model has the following advantages:*

- Views enable the developer to take precise control of the HTML that is rendered.
- You can use the Routing Engine to take precise control of URLs.
- Business logic, input logic, and user interface logic is separated into Models, Controllers, and 
  Views.
- Unit testing techniques and Test Driven Development (TDD) is possible.

*Disadvantages of MVC:*

- MVC is potentially more complex than Web Pages or Web Forms to understand.
- MVC forces you to separate your concerns (models, views, and controllers). Some programmers 
  may find this challenging.
- You cannot visually create a user interface by dragging controls onto a page.
- You must have a full understanding of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to develop Views.

---

*The Web Forms programming model has the following advantages:*

- Using server controls and Design View, you can design your page visually.
- You can use a broad range of highly functional controls that encapsulate a lot of functionality.
- You can display data without writing many lines of server-side code.
- The user interface, in the .aspx file is separated from input and business logic in code-behind files.

*Using a Web Forms site has some disadvantages:*

- The ASP.NET Web Forms page life cycle is an abstraction layer over HTTP and can behave in 
  unexpected ways. You must have a complete understanding of this life cycle in order to write 
  code in the correct event handlers.
- You do not have precise control over markup generated by server-side controls.
- Controls can add large amounts of markup and state information to the rendered HTML page. 
  This increases the time it takes to load pages.

---

c) It depends! What do you want to do? *see (b)*

For simple site/application I would use `HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript` (ClientSide) and `PHP/MySql` (ServerSide/Database)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I would answer to yours with details of the project I am working on: The backend provides jsons through REST calls (get and post), and I want to make a frontend with the simplest technology. Up until now, seems to me that the combination html+jquery is the best one (but I might be missing something with webforms!)

Answer (score 1):

When you get right down to it, there are two ways to create a form and both use client side code.

1. HTML
2. JavaScript

In almost all cases, using straight HTML is the better bet. (see 
 [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)).

A form, however, is fairly useless without a form handler, which requires some server side code. You can also use server side code to generate the client side code that creates the form itself.

ASP.NET is a group of server side technologies, some of which are useful for handling forms. There are plenty of alternatives to ASP.NET and I've used a wide–ish selection of those rather then ASP.NET so take the following with a pinch of salt as I might be a little misinformed about the details.

WebForms are the original ASP.NET way to do things. They seek to abstract as much of the client side code away from the developer as possible so they can create websites without understanding web standards. This makes things quick and Windows-like so long as you don't stray outside the lines, at which point it becomes a straitjacket.

ASP.NET MVC is the new (not so new now) and shiny approach which follows the design pattern made popular in the open source world by Ruby on Rails (said pattern also available in Catalyst, Django, Cake, Play!, and Mojito (to name an MVC framework for five different languages)).

> Can I consider AJAX useless for a simple webform (post-get of json) if I use jQuery?

Ajax is the term given to *Sending an HTTP request, and processing the response, using JavaScript and without leaving the page*. If you want to be passing JSON back and forth from the client then you almost have to use Ajax (any other approach raises the question of "Why JSON then?").

> Can I consider MVC too much for a simple webform?

What's a *simple* web form?

You need some form of server side technology for any form on the WWW. (JavaScript applications are another story).

> Which one would you choose, and why?

It's very hard to say since "a web form" is part of a solution, not a problem, and you haven't said what problem you are solving. In *general* though, I would use Perl on the server (since it is well supported by CPAN) and, either use entirely handcrafted JavaScript, a micro-library or two, or YUI (depending on how complex the problem was, and what level of browser support was needed). There is a *lot* of personal preference there though. Selecting technologies based on the skills you have available is usually the better bet.

Comment: Thanks for your really detailed answer, I find it really helpful. Answering your questions, I have to build a frontend for an already existing backend that provides json via api REST calls. So I'm just trying to find the best viable solution for implementing such a thing. For example, make a GET call for having some list of users and display them in a page, or make a POST call for booking an appointment, with a few parameters (still in json)--  So this is my definition of "simple webform", apologies for not having described it earlier. 

Thank you very much for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing you simply want to create a form to post information to an e-mail script or  database.

I think the easiest way to setup a web form is using HTML, JQuery and PHP. You simply create an HTML form, fetch the data using JQuery and send this information to a PHP script.

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<input id="name" placeholder="Name">
<input id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
<a href="#" id="send">Send</a>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#send").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post("send.php", { 
       name: $("#name").val(), 
       email: $("#email").val() 
   });
});
```

PHP:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
//do something with $name and $email
```

This is a really simple example and of course you should improve it.

EDIT: Using JQuery to post or retrieve data is basically AJAX.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I see that you are using PHP here, as I'm from the "windows" school, I would try to find the best solution for me, which would be (I imagine) trying to learn as little as possible of different technologies, with the perspective of deepening my knowledge in just one field. But your jQuery example  definitely makes sense even to be used with asp.net. Thanks!